# iOS - Capture loopback / output audio mix for the purpose of audio visualization

Tags: ios, iphone, core-audio

The following question asks basically the same thing but got no answers:

[How can I sample an audio stream on iOS for visualization regardless of the audio source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47100453/how-can-i-sample-an-audio-stream-on-ios-for-visualization-regardless-of-the-audi)

I'm completely new to iOS development, and I've had a rough time determining if this is even possible.

I managed to implement this for Android using the following: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html

This basically captures the ouput audio mix internally rather than from the microphone. It's perfect for what I'm doing.

Everything I've been reading so far about iOS is microphone-centric. Is it even possible to achieve similar functionality for iOS (specficially iPhone / iPad)?